# Checking for update settings in android

Tags: android, settings

How can Android check if the user selected (enabled) auto-update for apps?? I'm looking for a way to read user's update settings

Comment: What have you done until now?

Comment: Actually, I'm new to this. Aside from checking it thru Settings tab, I need a way in which my app can programatically read these user preferences. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Please take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask